# Autofac omit RegisterType when using Resolve?

Tags: autofac

Do I need to register a type before it is resolved?

```
builder.RegisterType<Driver>().As<IDriver>();

builder.Register(c => new Car(c.Resolve<IDriver>())).As<IVehicle>();
```

Or can I omit the register type line. Will the resolve register it for me?

Edit

Should I use RegisterType or Register

```
builder.Register(c => new Driver()).As<IDriver>();

builder.Register(c => new Car(c.Resolve<IDriver>())).As<IVehicle>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to register components before you can resolve dependencies on them.

In some specific situations, Autofac's `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` may automate the process.

More often, `ContainerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes()` is used to batch up registrations and cut down on repetition.

Comment: Thanks. Should I use register or register type . See updated question

Comment: You're welcome. Either is fine. On SO it is better to ask a new question if you need more information- makes it easier for others to find info later on. And don't forget to mark the question as answered :)